# RecyclerView not displaying any items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The following is the code for MainActivity where I use Async task to download data. But the data is not getting displayed.In the onPostExecute method movieList is containing 15 items but its showing as zero items in onCreate method for the same variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String YIFY_REQUEST_URL = "https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=15&page=1";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
int k = 1;

private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
MovieAdapter adapter;


List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    YifyAsyncTask yifyAsyncTask = new YifyAsyncTask();
    yifyAsyncTask.execute(YIFY_REQUEST_URL);
    adapter = new MovieAdapter(movieList);
    Log.v("Movie%count",movieList.size() +"");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);}
    else
    {   gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);}
    //recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    //recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    //recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);


    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = gridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // End has been reached

                Log.v("Yaeye!", "end called");

                int cur = adapter.getItemCount();

                // Do something
                new YifyAsyncTask().execute("https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=15&page=" + (++k));
                adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(cur,15);
                loading = true;

            }
        }
    });








}




 private class YifyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Movie>>{


    @Override
    protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url = createUrl(urls[0]);

        String jsonresponse = "";

        try{
            jsonresponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        }
        catch (IOException e){

        }





        return extractMovieFromJson(jsonresponse);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        //MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(movieList);
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(adapter.getItemCount(),15);
        movieList.addAll(moviesList);


    }

    private URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return url;

    }

    private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException{
        String jsonresponse = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.connect();

            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonresponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        }
        catch (IOException e){

        }
        finally {
            if(urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
        }

        return jsonresponse;

    }

    private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if(inputStream != null){
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream , Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        //Log.v("response",output.toString());
        return  output.toString();
    }


    private List<Movie> extractMovieFromJson(String movieJson){

        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(movieJson))
            return  null;

        try{
            JSONObject basejsonresponse = new JSONObject(movieJson);
            JSONObject data = basejsonresponse.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray movieArray = data.getJSONArray("movies");

            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject movie = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String movieName = movie.getString("title_long");
                String movieUrl = movie.getString("url").replaceAll("\\\\","");
                String movieImg = movie.getString("large_cover_image").replaceAll("\\\\","");

                //Log.v("url",movieImg);

                movieList.add(new Movie(movieName,movieUrl,movieImg));


            }
            return movieList;
        }
        catch (JSONException e){

        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

It worked before when I set the adapter in the onPostExecute method.But Later I removed that and set it in the onCreate method.But if I use the notifyDataSetChanged method in the onPostExecute movies are displaying. If I use notifyItemRangeChanged method even then data is not displaying.I'm not able to understand where I'm doing wrong.I'm a beginner and don't mind my bad coding style.

Comment: Title : `RecyclerView not displaying any items` - in question : `But if I use the notifyDataSetChanged method in the onPostExecute movies are displaying` - So they are displaying, they aren't displaying, it is very unclear the actual problem?

Comment: They are not displaying.

Comment: ok - they are not displaying because you are not telling your adapter instance that something has changed when you add the items to your `Collection` in `onPostExecute`

Comment: But I had already added the items to the list initially. Only when I scroll then I had to tell  the adapter instance that something has changed since I'm requesting more movies...right?

Comment: `But I had already added the items to the list initially` - no, you are making an asynchronous request every time. This line `adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(cur,15);` does nothing. Handle all logic for appending the `Collection` and notifying the `RecyclerAdapter` for new paginated items in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: It's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call notifyDataSetChanged() method the way you are doing, that method is supposed to be called on your onPostExecute() or a method called from it.  Since you are executing an asynchronous request, see below.  Your next line(adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(cur,15);) is not guaranteed/expected to be called after the line below.

```
new YifyAsyncTask().execute("https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=15&page=" + (++k));
```

Comment: Yeah...It's working now.I have added that particular code in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: Glad it works.  If this answer helped you feel free to accept it as answer so it helps others.